# Problem with Time zone configuration Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, timezone, config, datetime-select

I've been having some problems with the configuration of timezone.

So I've seen some posts/questions about this topic and some say I should add the following configuration in the "application.rb".

```
config.time_zone = "Brasilia"
```

I've done that, but even after configuring this, if a run the following code in rails console I get (GMT+00:00) UTC

```
Time.zone
```

The same happens when a do

```
Time.now.in_time_zone
```

It responds in GMT 0.

Another problem that I think relates to this, is when choosing a datetime with the datetime_select tag. It seems as it's showing the right time but when the field is saved to the db is also on the UTC +00.

Comment: A question: are you trying to use different timezones dynamically? or are you trying to set up your I18n locale?

Answer (score 0):

have you checked your {environments}.rb file (e.g. environments/development.rb)? The config values in application.rb are overridden by the same values in the environment .rb files. Perhaps you have GMT set in development.rb?

When I added `config.time_zone = "Brasilia"` to my development.rb file and ran `rails c`, I get:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > Time.zone
 => (GMT-03:00) Brasilia
```